# Spring JPA select query with where clause to AWS Postgresql RDS takes very long time (>3 hours)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, amazon-rds

I have a `StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>` with a method

```
@Query(value = "select a from Student a where a.isActive = true and lower(a.name) = lower(?1) and university_id in (?2)")

List<Student> fetchUniversityStudents(@Param("name") String name,@Param("universityIds") List<Long> universityIds);
```

This method when executed in a **new transaction** `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`takes a very long time (>3 hours) to execute, which times out my REST API and does not return expected result on time.

I even tried with nativeQuery but no change in the result.

Is there anything incorrect with the query?

For some records it returns in `< 3ms.`

Sometimes it fails to complete even after `3 hours`

Is there a better way to get the list with some modifications in the above query?

Or could it be possible that this `student` row / table is **locked** for `select` queries due to some other operation?

I can post some more operations around this api if it helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much data is there? There is a function `lower()` in there which can severly impact the execution/processing time. How much data is there in `Student` 5 columns or 500, how did you define your relationships (eager/lazy) what is being loaded. Is it really the query that is taking that long or the response to be written.

Comment: @M.Deinum
I have now removed lower() and tried, got the same timeout, the student Entity is a simple one(about 5 columns with lazy loading), it does not have much details . RDS is r5.4xlarge and number of records are < 500. It returns within 3ms for the first record, and times out for the 2nd record.

Comment: The fact that you have lazy loading doesn't mean it doesn't load, depending on what you do it still might retrieve everything with N additional queries. Still without investigating **what** is slow this is going to be impossible to answer. The fact that it takes 3 hours is also an indication that you have somewhere misconfigured your connection pool (and maybe even using things in a wrong way). But investigate, use a profiler and see what is taking so long.